# is there an equivalent to python's request module in Java for working on REST based App

Tags: java, python, rest, http

I am looking for an equivalent Java API lib which can do same things as Python's HTTP [Requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/).

Key features of the Requests lib:

1. One-step initialization of an HTTP request returns `response` object.
2. The `response` object contains methods/member-vars to quickly access response status, headers, body/data, and a JSON-parsing method.

Comment: It's probably worth saying what you like about *Request* in contract to *urllib2* so people will know the kind of library you're looking for.  If you just want code to do HTTP requests that's in the standard JRE.

Comment: I Want to work with a REST based App. which is actually quite easy with python's Request module!!

Answer (score 7):

Although I've not had the chance to use it much [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html) looks like a good option for people looking for the eloquence and ease of use of Python's Requests module in Java.

For simple use cases it looks much quicker to get things done than Httpcomponents (which it uses under the hood).

Comment: Just an update on my experiences with Unirest (if anyone's interested): having used it now for a couple of projects that are running in production, simple stuff is much quicker and easier with Unirest.

For 90% of stuff (at least), Unirest does a really good job of hiding/abstracting the complexity/verbosity of HttpComponents. It has a lot of boilerplate functionality I find myself often building on top of HttpClient, like deserializing a response to an object of a specific type.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but posting for posterity:

After trying Unirest, it didn't feel  like Python Requests and I couldn't make it work for my needs.  My key complaints were cookie/session management were intentionally left out.

https://github.com/hsiafan/requests is working fine for me so far and has session based cookie management implemented transparently.  This one was "inspired by" Python's requests so should be comparable.

Comment: hsiafan/requests seems to no longer exist

Answer (score 2):

You can use either regular `HttpUrlConnection` (that is a part of your JDK) or Jakarta [Httpcomponents client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html).

Comment: +1 for HttpClient. It grinds my gears how people are still persisting in using UtlConnection and InputStreams

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can use see the example

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://www.google.com/search?q=Java+Programming"))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .GET()
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = httpClient.send(httpRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(httpResponse.body());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading about the [Groovy RESTClient](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/RESTClient) libs in a book on the [Spock test framework](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/). The book recommended it as an alternative to [Spring RestTemplate](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) (which isn't so bad itself).

```
@Grab(group=’org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder’, module=’http-builder’, version=’0.7')
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
```

It returns JSON has a hashmap.